# Como SobreCargar Operadores

Tags: c#

Se pueden Sobrecargar operadores pero yo no logro entender de manera clara `¿Como es su sintaxis correctamente y simple? y ¿Para Que puede ser utilizado?` navegando por la web encontrado diferentes ejemplos muy confusos que no son claros en la cual me provoca una mayor nivel de confusión para utilizar este operador para sobrecargar operadores lo único que se que es para SobreCarga de operadores y que se declara algo así ademas cuando lo escribo me muestra que su sintaxis es errónea

```
public static Metodo operator+(int a, int b)
 {

 }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Por ejemplo, si quiero sumar dos enteros(int) me da como resultado otro entero, si quiero dividir dos enteros me da un fraccionario(single?), si quiero sumar dos fechas me da una fecha y asi(en caso de las fechas no esta sobrecargado creo que es datetime.add), se llama operacion binaria (combino dos cosas y me da una) y lo que usamos son los **operadores binarios**

Bien ahora quiero sumar dos cosas locas que el lenguaje no lo contempla, por ejemplo sumo dos personas y me da una persona:

```
Persona Jose = new Persona(70, 40);
Persona Juan = new Persona(80, 30);
Persona Pedro = Jose + Juan;
```

esto el c# no nos permite pero si sobrecargamos el operado, **en este caso el + que es binario osea que toma 2 objetos y devuelve 1** y le decimos que hacer en ese caso:

```
public class Persona
{
    public int peso;
    public int edad;

    public Persona(int p, int e)  // constructor
    {
        peso = p;
        edad = e;
    }

    // sobrecargamos el + que toma 2 Personas y devuelve Persona:
    public static Persona operator+(Persona a, Persona b)
    {
        return new Persona(a.peso + b.peso, a.edad + b.edad);
    }
}
```

ahora nos damos cuenta que Pedro pesa 150kg y tiene una edad de 70 años, pero es muy util para cosas concretas por ejemplo para sacar promedios o si quiero saber cuanto peso lleva un asensor entonces sumo las personas :), y cosas asi.

No es muy usado. en realidad es una funcion, si la haces con el formato habitual tambien funciona.

```
Persona Pedro = Jose.Agregar(Juan).Agregar(Julio)
```